# Simplifying $\nabla\times(Ax)$ by using index notation

Tags: summation, index-notation

I'm completely new to Einstein's summation notation/index notion and had a go at simplying the following expression:
$$\nabla\times(Ax)$$
For a 3x3 matrix A and a vector x.

My attempt:
I know
$$Ax=a_{ij}x_j$$
$$\nabla\times v=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_jv_k$$
$$\partial_ix_j=\delta_{ij}$$
$$a_{ij}\delta_{jk}=a_{ik}$$
If we define a vector $c=Ax$ then $c_k=a_{kj}x_j$
Therefore
$$\nabla\times(Ax)=\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(a_{kl}x_l)$$
since they commute then
$$=\epsilon_{ijk}a_{kl}(\partial_jx_l)$$
By applying the third equation
$$=\epsilon_{ijk}(a_{kl}\delta_{jl})$$
Now apply the forth equation
$$=\epsilon_{ijk}a_{kj}$$
Thats where I got stuck on, if I didn't misunderstood anything, since j and k are the summation index, this term can be futher simplified but I don't know what to do next apart from brute force numeration. If you can lend a hand, thank you!

Comment: Dummy / summation indices can't always be simplified away. If they could, they wouldn't appear everywhere. Like in your $a_{ij}x_j$. You can't simplify away the $j$ there, so why would you expect to be able to simplify away $j$ and $k$ in your final expression?

Comment: @Arthur ahhhhh, don't know why I got stuck  into that thought process, thank you! Would you mind checking if the rest of my argument is sound? It's kind of weird to me that x is completely eliminated from the equation.

Comment: When you say $\partial_ix_j=\delta_{ij}$, that looks like $x_j$ means the $j$'th _coordinate function_, not the $j$th component of some arbitrary vector field. It's an unfortunate mix-up.

Comment: @Arthur so I should state clearly that $x_j$ represents the j-th component?

Comment: Since $\nabla\times(Ax)$ has to be a vector even though $A$ is a matrix, you shouldn't expect any result another than a multiple of $\epsilon_{ijk}A_{jk}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say ‘they commute’, you're effectively assuming that the matrix $ A $ is constant and only the vector $ x $ is varying.  I'll assume that that's what you intended.

As @Arthur said in a comment, you can't always simplify indices away.  In index notation, the final answer is $ \epsilon _ { i j k } a _ { k j } $; you can't simplify it any further.  (Although if you'd like the indices to come in a consistent order, you can use the antisymmetry of $ \epsilon $ to make it $ - \epsilon _ { i k j } a _ { k j } $ or $ \epsilon _ { k i j } a _ { k j } $ and then relabel the indices to $ - \epsilon _ { i j k } a _ { j k } $ or $ \epsilon _ { i j k } a _ { i k } $, in case either of those looks nicer to you.)

Or if you want to translate the answer back into vector/matrix notation, then you can look through the known operations from matrices to vectors and see if you can find one that matches this.  In this case, I don't recognize it.  But that's the beauty of index notation: you don't have to worry about whether anybody has thought of your operation before; you have the notation for it regardless.

ETA:  And for the record, I checked your calculation, and it's correct (assuming that $ A $ is a constant matrix and $ x $ is the vector whose components are the coordinates).

ETA again:  I've thought of something that's similar to this operation that takes a matrix (in $ 3 $ dimensions) with components $ a _ { i j } $ to a vector with components $ \epsilon _ { i j k } a _ { j k } $.  If you have two vectors with components $ v _ i $ and $ w _ i $, then their dot product is $ v _ i w _ i $ and their cross product has components $ \epsilon _ { i j k } v _ j w _ k $.  But there's also the tensor product, a matrix with components $ v _ i w _ j $.  This contains all of the information in both the dot and cross products; for example, the dot product is the trace of the tensor product.  And how do you get the *cross* product from the tensor product?  It's this mystery operation!  So I still don't know what you call it or any symbol for it in vector algebra, but it does come up.  (Although note this technicality: the answer to your question is actually the *opposite* of the operation that takes a tensor product to a cross product, because of the extra minus sign.)

Comment: So they only commute if matrix A has a constant component $a_ij$? If thats established is this "proof" valid or did I mess it up? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Right, if the $a_{ij}$ are not constant, then the step from $\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(a_{kl}x_l)$ to $\epsilon_{ijk}a_{kl}\partial_jx_l$ is not valid; instead, it would become $\epsilon_{ijk}x_l\partial_ja_{kl}+\epsilon_{ijk}a_{kl}\partial_jx_l$ by the Product Rule for differentiation. And that new term wouldn't simplify any further.

Comment: @OrangeSpace :  I've added a clue to the identity of this mystery operation that is the answer.